# Convert regex BBcode pattern to HTML regex

Tags: html, regex, bbcode

I'm working on small project and stuck with bbcode pattern regex convert into html pattern regex.

Currently code working using `[pre] [/pre]` BBcode; I want to code work HTML regex:

```
$pattern = '#\[pre\](.*?)\[\/pre\]#si';

$pattern = '#\[.?pre\]#si';
```

I try to convert it as below, but it's not working (Didn't get expect results):

```
$pattern = '#\<pre\>(.*?)\<\/pre\>#si';

$pattern = '#\<.?pre\>#si';
```

Comment: No...simple php file 
<pre>regex use check inside pre tag conetent</pre>
 

[pre]It's working fine when using BBcode and first two regex[/pre]

just want it work with html <pre> tag

Comment: what is the expected output and input

Comment: hide the content inside on <pre></pre> tag..... program working on BBcode ([pre][/pre]) but not with html..That's why i need that two regex format with html pre tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how you're using the regex but the following works for me:

```
<?php
$text = "<pre>regex use check inside pre tag conetent</pre>";
$found = preg_match( '#\<pre\>(.*?)\<\/pre\>#si', $text, $matches);

echo $matches[1]; // prints: "regex use check inside pre tag conetent"
?>
```